# Graph-based representation for land borders

Tags: machine-learning, graph, deep-learning, word2vec

I'm trying to get the 2D vectors from a set of countries. I've built my graph by the following process (see the picture):

- each node represents a country
- each edge represents the land border between 2 countries (or nodes)

[image: Graph representation of land borders]

I'm using Node2vec library to manage it but results are not relevant.

```
countries = [
    "France", "Andorra", 
    "Spain", "Italy", "Switzerland", 
    "Germany", "Portugal"
]

crossing_borders = [
    ("France", "Andorra"),
    ("France", "Spain"),
    ("Andorra", "Spain"),
    ("France", "Italy"),
    ("France", "Switzerland"),
    ("Italy", "Switzerland"),
    ("Switzerland", "Italy"),
    ("Switzerland", "Germany"),
    ("France", "Germany"),
    ("Spain", "Portugal")
]

graph.add_nodes_from(countries)
graph.add_edges_from(crossing_borders)

# Generate walks
node2vec = Node2Vec(graph, dimensions=2, walk_length=2, num_walks=50)

# Learn embeddings 
model = node2vec.fit(window=1)
```

[image]

I would like to get countries which are sharing the land border closer each other. As below, Spain is too far from France. I only considered direct border that's why `walk-length = 2`.

Do you have any idea that would fit my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `Node2Vec` is basd on word2Vec, and thus like word2vec, requires a large amount of varied training data, and shows useful results when learning dense high-dimensional vectors per entity.

A mere 7 'words' (country-nodes) with a mere 10 'sentences' of 2 words each (edge-pairs) thus isn't expecially likely to do anything useful. (It wouldn't in word2vec.)

These countries literally are regions on a sphere. A sphere's surface can be mapped to a 2-D plane - hence, 'maps'. If you just want a 2-D vector for each country, which reflects their relative border/distance relationships, why not just lay your 2-D coordinates over an actual map large enough to show all the countries, and treat each country as its 'geographical center' point?

Or more formally: translate the x-longitude/y-latitude of each country's geographical center into whatever origin-point/scale you need.

If this simple, physically-grounded approach is inadequate, then being explicit about why it's inadequate might suggest next steps. Something that's an incremental transformation of those starting points to meet whatever *extra* constraints you want may be the best solution.

For example, if your not-yet-stated formal goal is that "every country-pair with an actual border should be closer than any country-pair without a border", then you could write code to check that, list any deviations, and try to 'nudge' the deviations to be more compliant with that constraint. (It might not be satisfiable; I'm not sure. And if you added other constraints, like "any country pair with just 1 country between them should be closer than any country pair with 2 countries between them", satisfying them all at once could become harder.)

Ultimately, next steps may depend on exactly *why* you want these per-country vectors.

Another thing worth checking out might be the algorithms behind 'force-directed graphs'. There, after specifying a graph's desired edges/edge-lengths, and some other parameters, a physics-inspired simulation will arrive at some 2-d layout that tries to satisfy the inputs. See for example from the JS world:

https://github.com/d3/d3-force